# How do I pass the selected value/text from telerik Kendo autocomplete to my Controller?

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, controller, telerik, view

How do I pass the selected value/text from telerik Kendo autocomplete to my Controller? I saw the examples but they are accessing the selected item on the same view NOT passing to the controller. Also I am creating my autocomplete using viewbag as datasource.
Updated: I would like to access the selected value on AccessSelecteditem(txtNames) function when submit button is clicked. I reason I am trying to do it this way is, this approach works for html.dropdownlist.

```
My kendo autocomplete in view.

@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Home")
@Code
Html.Kendo().AutoComplete() _
.Name("txtNames") _
.DataTextField("Text") _
.BindTo(ViewBag.txtData) _
.Filter("Contains") _
.Suggest(True) _
.MinLength(4) _
.Render()
End Code      
End Using
<input type="submit" value="Submit">


Function Index() As ActionResult
‘ Here I am storing the selectitemlist into a viewbag which I used as a datasource for my kendo combobox
    ViewBag. txtData = getDataForKendo()
    Return View()
 End Function

Function AccessSelecteditem(txtNames) As ActionResult
‘ Here I am trying to get the selected value/text value from the kendo   comobox.
Dim selectedItem = txtNames.selecteditem       
    Return View()
End Function
```

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: What you have there is a AutoComplete, not a ComboBox. Other than that, does the function `AccessSelecteditem()` get hit?

Comment: @chiapa you are right, I updated my question. Thanks.